# Надо вывести сообщение после последнего элемента массива

Tags: javascript

Надо вывести сообщение после последнего элемента массива, а оно выводиться после каждого. Как исправить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо!

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let currentIndex = 0;
let currentLimit = 1;
let arrLenght = arr.indexOf(arr[arr.length - 1]);

newButton.onclick = function showArray() {
  for (; currentIndex < currentLimit && currentIndex < arr.length; currentIndex++) {
    console.log(arr[currentIndex]);
    if (currentIndex = arrLenght){
        console.log('End')
    }
  };

  currentLimit++;
}
```

Comment: `if (currentIndex == arrLenght - 1) {`

Comment: Вот я дурак! Я благодарю вас:)